# envio de correo electronico con php desde un servidor local

Tags: php, html5, gmail

estoy realizando una aplicacion web y necesito enviar los datos del formulario a un correo electronico especifico, aca el codigo del formulario

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>prueba</title>
    </head>
        <body>
        <center>
            <form action="enviar.php" method="post"" name="contacto" id ="contacto" >
                Nombre completo 
                <input name="nombre" type="text" id="nombre completo"size="30" maxlength="100">
                <br>
                <br>
                Correo electronico 
                <input name="email" type="text" onBlur="MM_validateForm('email','','NisEmail');return document.MM_returnValue" size="25" maxlength="100" >
                <br>
                <br>
                Población 
                <input name="poblacion" type="text" onBlur="MM_validateForm('poblacion','','R');return document.MM_returnValue" size="20" maxlength="60">
                <br>
                <br>
                Sexo
                <br>
                <br>
                <input type="radio" name="GrupoOpciones1" value="1"id="GrupoOpciones1_0" />
                Hombre
                <br>
                <input type="radio" name="GrupoOpciones1" value="2"id="GrupoOpciones1_1"/> Mujer
                <br>
                <br>
                Aficiones
                <br>
                <textarea cols="50" rows="5" name="comentarios"></textarea>
                <br>
                <br>
                Que opina de nuestra pagina
                <br>
                <br>
                <input type="radio" name="GrupoOpciones2" value="mucho" >me ha gustado mucho
                <br>
                <input type="radio" name="GrupoOpciones2" value="regular" >no esta mal
                <br>
                <input type="radio" name="GrupoOpciones2" value="mal" >no me ha gustado nada
                <br>
                <br>
                Danos tu opinion
                <br>
                <textarea cols="50" rows="5" name="opinion"></textarea>
                <br>
                <br>
                <input type="submit" value="Enviar formulario">
                <input type="Reset" value="Borrar datos">
            </form>
        </center>
        </body>
</html>
```

y este es el codigo del proceso que lo recibe

```
<?php
    error_reporting(1);
    $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
    $mail = $_POST['email'];
    $poblacion = $_POST['poblacion'];
    $sexo=$_POST['GrupoOpciones1'];
    $aficiones=$_POST['comentarios'];
    $radio= $_POST['GrupoOpciones2'];
    $opinion=$_POST['opinion'];
    $header = 'From: ' .$mail. ", de la poblacion ".$poblacion."\r\n";
    $header .= "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion() . " \r\n";
    $header .= "Mime-Version: 1.0 \r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Type: text/plain";

    $mensaje = "Este mensaje fue enviado por " . $nombre . " \r\n";
    $mensaje .= "Su e-mail es: " . $mail . " \r\n";
    $mensaje .= "sexo" . $_POST['GrupoOpciones1'] . " \r\n";
    $mensaje .= "aficiones " . $_POST['comentarios'] . " \r\n";
    $mensaje .= "que opinas de nuestra pagina" . $_POST['GrupoOpciones2'] . " \r\n";
    $mensaje .="danos tu opinion".$_POST['opinion'] . " \r\n";
    $mensaje .= "Enviado el " . date('d/m/Y', time());

    $para = 'angelgutierrez1983@gmail.com';
    $asunto = 'prueba de correo';

    mail('angelgutierrez1983@gmail.com', 'probando', $mensaje /*$header*/);

    echo 'mensaje enviado correctamente';
?>
```

trabajo desde mi servidor localhost, realize varias configuraciones en el xampp y el php.ini pero igual no me funciona, trabajo con windows 10 64bit y el con xampp version 3.2.2

Comment: La configuración de un servidor local de PHP puede producirte ciertos problemas. Puedes ver este video en donde está detallado
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k02_BevpFD4 También puedes optar por hacerlo desde el cliente, como por ejemplo con JavaScript directamente. Te recomiendo esta libreria, tiene un CDN y es muy fácil de utilizar.
https://www.smtpjs.com/

Comment: te recomiendo usar PHP 5 usando class y metodos y no usar php funcional

Comment: @HugoQuiñónez es libreria la pueod usar de forma local? por que el problema es ese que no tengo acceso al hosting del usuario

Answer (score 3, accepted):

por recomendación no utilices la función mail, prueba usando una librería te recomiendo PHPMailer y utiliza un servidor smtp para que esos correos si lleguen a su destino, por ejemplo mailgun, sendmail esos son buenos.

Comment: Hola te sugiero revisar [answer], saludos.